# Fetching variable from the database

Tags: php, json, ajax, xml

I need help on fetching and passing the JSON data to a variable in my JavaScript file. How do I achieve this?

```
passing data.js using ajax
speedTest.info = data.js;

json file
var data = {    
"js": [{"case_id":"1","case_name":"wizi","first_name":"pangras","mkoa":"Dodoma","wilaya":"Dodoma mjini","siku":"Jumatatu","police_district":"police_district","longitude":35.746062,"latitude":-6.1630475}
]}
```

Comment: That's not JSON, it's JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data.js` is JavaScript, not JSON. So you can simply load it like any other script.

```
<script src="data.js"></script>
<script>
speedTest.info = data;
</script>
```

If you want to fetch dynamic data from a database, you can change `src="data.js"` to `src="data.php"`. The PHP script can do something like:

```
$results = $pdo->query("SELECT ...");
$data = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
header("Content-type: text/javascript");
echo "var data = " . json_encode(["js" => $data]) . ";";
```

Comment: but i want those data inside variable js to be retrived from the database @Barmar

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to get it from the database.